# My www version has better metrics than the non-www, so I'm preferring it in search console now. What else do I need to do?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, 301-redirect, no-www

I am working on a website which was originally registered in Google Search Console as `http://example.com/`. After a few months I noticed that the   `http://www.example.com/` has higher domain authority (DA) and page authority (PA) than the `non-www` form of the same website.

So I made the www version (`http://www.example.com/`) as preferred in the Google search console. Now pages are indexed well in the google with `www` version.

I want some suggestions regarding the 301 redirect that i am going to make from the `non-www` to the `www` version (`http://www.example.com/`) of the website. (The `www` version property is not added in the search console.)

- Should I add the `www` version property separately in search console and Google Analytics?
- Will there be any backlinking and other issues?
- What are the possible SEO consequences after I make 301 redirect?

Comment: If you are redirecting from one to the other, all the authority will get passed.   It doesn't really matter for SEO which one you choose.   If you like the look of your URL without the www and those extra four characters to type, you can go back to that.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a 301-Redirect, which is a server response that claims google that this site just moved to another domain and isn't just temporarily unavailable or something.

On top of that you should use the "canonical url" meta tag for google, to consolidate duplicate pages/content.

Here you can find more about that: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en